# Does refreshing the site help to get new nofications?

Tags: support

I was wondering if refreshing from time to time actualy shows me new nofications of reputation changes? I guess it might help sometimes if internet connections are slow or if I am on a protected proxy (like I am now).

Does refreshing actualy do anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unless you are using a browser that doesn't support websockets, in which case you will never get updates at all.

Even on a slow or proxied connection, websockets send/receive a very small amount of data compared to a refresh of the entire page, so should perform better in any case.

Comment: one more question. My pc is often in sleep mode. will any nofications also show up when I wake my pc or do I have to refresh then?

Comment: @codermaster You'll almost certainly need to refresh after waking the machine.

Comment: Okey then that is clear, thanks for helping.